# Подскажите теорию по синтаксическому анализатору

Tags: pascal

Нужны примеры с разбором аналогичных заданий с комментариями. Тот пример, который я написал, я не понял. Помогите с заданием, в интернете вообще ничего хорошего нет на эту тему. 
[Здесь задание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/65168/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-pascal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В профессиональном программировании стандартом является связка flex/bison. Конкретно к синтаксическому разбору относится bison. Примеры использования из сети:

- [первое знакомство](http://trpl.narod.ru/CC_Bison.htm)
- [примеры](http://lib.profi.net.ua/doc/info_sites/www.linux.org.ru/books/GNU/bison/bison_5.html)

Answer (score 1):

Plex/Pyacc не пойдет ? http://wiki.freepascal.org/Plex_and_Pyacc
Для С/С++ всегда пользуюсь связкой flex/bison (или lex/yacc для чистого Си) + свой универсальный базовый класс для хранения полученных данных (*) -- быстро, легко, идет в комплекте с любой сборкой GNU toolchain (в частности MinGW).

```
struct Sym {
    string tag;    // тэг типа, указывает тип значения
    string val;    // значение объекта в текстовом представлении
    Sym(string T,string V); Sym(string V); // конструкторы: полный и sym-
    vector<Sym*> nest; void push(Sym*);    // упорядоченные вложенные данные
    map<string,Sym*> lookup;               // именованные поля
    virtual string head(); string pad(int);// \ вывод дампа объекта в виде дерева
    virtual strign dump(int depth);        // /
};

struct Integer:Sym { Integer(string); long long val; string head(); };
struct Number:Sym { Number(string); double val; string head(); };
```

Подробно теория расписана в Книге Дракона, если нужна полноценная собственная реализация, а не курсовая -- ищите алгоритмы синтеза конечных автоматов для регулярных выражений и EBNF грамматик.

Если для курсовой и нужен ручной разбор (не подходят lex/yacc генераторы), адаптируйте под паскал мануал по написанию компилятора для LLVM:

1. Kaleidoscope: Tutorial Introduction and the Lexer
   http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl01.html
2. Kaleidoscope: Implementing a Parser and AST
   h t tp://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl02.html

Comment: вот [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLddc343N7YqgDKydMAp_72-vr1qK8tx3E) делаю на ютубе курс на базе [PLAI](https://github.com/ponyatov/PLAI) по лексическому программированию (* подскажите как это правильно называется -- парсинг, и элементы реализации динамических языков или их рантаймов для обработки данных)